# Android - How create NTLM Authentification with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, ntlm, okhttp

I'm trying to call a SOAP request with Retrofit and OkHttpClient, but I can not access to my WSDL file located in a URL with NTLM Auth.

How can I make a NTLM Auth with OkHttpClient?

I have tried this solution: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/206
But the class doesn't compile cause of the apache files...

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am facing a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

you should add this to your

> build.gradle

```
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
```

I think it help you

Comment: I am not working in this anymore, but thank you so much for your answered

Comment: https://github.com/netcosports/Android_Ntlm
here is apache free realisation

Comment: What does this solution do??